# How can i translate a parametric equation to cartesian

Tags: parametric

The parametric equations are :
$$
x=16\sin^3(t)$$
and
$$y=13\cos(t)-5\cos(2t)-2\cos(3t)-\cos(4t)
$$

with $t$ from $-\pi$ to $+\pi$

so I'm new to this kind of equations and i really don't know how to start the conversion... Can someone help me?

Comment: On the right hand side, try using the formulas for the cosine of a sum.  That is, $\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$, but replace the $a$ and $b$ with appropriate integer multiples of $t$.

Comment: is this partial solution with the prosthaphaeresis formula correct: $y/13*5*2=cos(1+2)-cos(3+4)$?

Comment: No.  What you've written is that $y$ should be a constant value of $130\cdot [\cos(3)-\cos(7)]$, which is definitely not true.  You can check that when you plug in $t$-values of $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ into the parametric equation for $y$, you get different output values for $y$.  So $y$ can't be constant.

Comment: ok, so if the y value cant be constat, how can i solve it (i should study much more...)